# set theory proof explanation

Tags: set-theory, proof-explanation

The following lemma is taken from the book 'Introduction to Set Theory' by Hrbacek and Jech.
chapter $6$ normal form
[image]

Can anyone explain to me why the first sentence holds ( the existence of $\delta$)?

Comment: Because for $\alpha>0, \beta<\gamma$ implies $\alpha\cdot \beta<\alpha\cdot \gamma$. This should be somewhere in the book.

Comment: Yes, it is somewhere in the book. But how we apply this in the first sentence? I don't see the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the multiplication being monotone, $\alpha\geq 1$ implies 
$\alpha\cdot (\gamma+1)\geq 1\cdot (\gamma+1)$

Comment: It's good to see you here again!

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hi, Asaf!

Answer (score 1):

{$\beta$ $\in$ Ord|$\alpha\beta>\gamma$$\land\beta\le\gamma+1$} is non empty,it has a least elemant $\beta_{0}$

Assume $\beta_{0}$ is a limit ordinal ,then  $\alpha\beta_{0}=sup${$\alpha\beta^{'}_{0}$|$\beta^{'}_{0}<\beta_{0}$}

but since $\forall\beta^{'}_{0}<\beta_{0},\alpha\beta^{'}_{0}\le\gamma$

$\alpha\beta_{0}$=$sup${$\alpha\beta^{'}_{0}$|$\beta^{'}_{0}<\beta_{0}$}$\le\gamma$ a controdiction.

Answer (score 0):

$\delta=\gamma+1$ also I think $\alpha \geq 1$

Comment: How we know that $\gamma+1$ is a successor ordinal?

Comment: Whatever the ordinal $\gamma$ is, $\gamma + 1$ is its successor.

Comment: @Idonknow: This question shows that you need to either take a break for a couple of hours from the topic, or start reading the part about ordinals from the beginning.